# Add a delimited layer in QGIS (.csv), but do not add all columns

Tags: qgis, data-transfer, open-data-kit

I am using the odk app to collect data and a heading of the form is required.

This heading is imported in QGIS as column as well, when I add the data as delimited layer, but it does not contain relevant information. Is there a way to remove certain columns while adding the .csv-file (skiping empty fields does not work)?

Image 1: xls-form (for ODK)
[image]

Image 2: Attribute Table in QGIS
[image]

I can delete the columns manuelly afterwards. But would like to know if there is a way to do it automatically (so either in the xls-form or before importing data in the settings of "adding a delimited text layer").

Comment: Can you include a image example of what this table/data looks like in your question?

Answer (score 1):

When importing a Delimited Text Layer in QGIS, you can tell it to ignore a given number of header lines - see the attached screencap, under "Record options." I'm using QGIS 2.18.2 (Las Palmas); I don't know if this is available on earlier versions.

[image]

Comment: Another idea might be to load the whole table, and then select only the relevant records using some appropriate expression (something like fieldA != None), and exporting that selection to a new layer.

Comment: By using the "Record options", it just deletes rows, not columns unfortunatly. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, I think I mistook your question for meaning rows, not columns. Well, in either case, I can imagine a relatively simple R or Python script that would read in the file, select only the columns you want, then write a new file which you can give to QGIS. That would be straight-forward data manipulation; not GIS per se. If that sounds helpful, I can probably write a script and post it here.

Comment: Sounds great. I'd really appeciate, if you could help me with the script, as I have never written something similar.